# Execute shell command when receiving properly constructed email

Tags: python, bash, shell, email

Having failed to find an answer to this elsewhere, I am opening this question more widely.

I need to execute a bash shell command when a properly constructed email is received (I'm using GMail) using Python. I have previously used Python to send emails, but the only solution I have yet found is to use feedparser and Google Atom, which I don't like. I would suggest that a keyword could exist in either the subject or body of the email; security is not an issue (I don't think) as the consequence is benign.

The bash command to execute will actually call another scripts to send the latest jpg from my Python motion detection routine which runs independently.

Comment: You want to connect to gmail via python, or receive local `mail`, which are sent from your gmail? For the former case, have a look at a python based package called `gmail-notify`

Comment: I need to parse emails sent to my GMail account in order to execute a command. But it all has to happen in Python.

Comment: Check `gmail-notify` code then. On your distro, the name may vary slightly... but you can google for the code :)

Comment: How often you want to check your mail box?

Comment: Every 10 mins should be fine

Comment: I've done something similar with `fetchmail` and `procmail` in the past...

Comment: Excellent responses. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would construct a script.

Create a script which polls the GMail inbox and then executes necessary scripts if correct incoming emails are detected.

Use [IMAPClient](http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/) to handle GMail reading.

Detect the incoming email format using Python built-in string matching or [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Execute the bash script using Python [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subproces#subprocess) module.

Run the script as a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job on the server.

[Deploy the script and necessary dependencies using virtualenv](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/).

Answer (score 0):

procmail does this kind of thing trivally - checking the format of an incoming email and running a shell script that is.  There's no need to reinvent the wheel

I'm not entirely clear from your description how python fits in to what you want to do..

Hope this helps!